# llvm: how to replace function A to another function using llvm api?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I want to replace "function A" call to "function B" call. Currently, I've inserted "function B", I think ReplaceInstWithInst() may help, however, I don't know how to locate "function A". How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all the functions in a module by using `mod->getFunction("functionA");`, as described [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a3f156c68d0efa530f05698ca15d66593).

Comment: @winter333 No problem. The LLVM doc is really poor, doxygen/header files are your best friends!